# Why is the XPath I found in Chrome different from the one in the code?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I've found a simple Python script that has xPath in it, but it's the same as the one I found using Google Chrome.

```
    lsd = scrapy.Selector(response).xpath('//input[@name="lsd"]/@value').extract_first()
    m_ts = scrapy.Selector(response).xpath('//input[@name="m_ts"]/@value').extract_first()
    li = scrapy.Selector(response).xpath('//input[@name="li"]/@value').extract_first()
```

The xpath I found in Google Chrome is as follows:

```
     //*[@id="basic-info"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]
```

But the one I found in the code is as follows:

```
item['sex'] = ''.join(scrapy.Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="basic-info"]/div/div[2]/div/table/tr/td[2]/div/text()').extract())
```

**They are different, and I don't know why. How did the coder come up with the latter?**

Comment: `[@id="basic-info"]/div/div[2]/div/table/tr/td[2]/div/` is incorrect because of extra `/` at the end of expression...

Comment: It's this one, I'll edit it. //*[@id="basic-info"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]

Comment: This is the one in the code: '//*[@id="basic-info"]/div/div[2]/div/table/tr/td[2]/div/text()

It worked just fine, it had  /  in the end and then `text()`

Comment: `//*[@id="basic-info"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]` intend to return you first `div` node while `//*[@id="basic-info"]/div/div[2]/div/table/tr/td[2]/div/tex‌​t()` - text node of the `div`

Comment: It's not clear to me why you expect them to be the same. In general, for any node in your XML, there's an infinite number of ways of reaching it and therefore an infinite number of valid XPath expressions. In this case however your first lot of XPath expressions select an @value attribute, the next one selects an element, and the next one selects a text node, so they are clearly designed to do different things.

Comment: Thank you. I'll execute the script and come back to you.